# Convert query from laravel eloquent to raw sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Can someone help me convert this eloquent query to SQL query because I'm trying to study this piece of code. And I'm having a hard time understanding what this code is because I'm new to eloquent but I have some experience with SQL.

```
$checkInDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($request->start_date));
$checkOutDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($request->end_date));

$availableRooms = $this->_availablerooms->from('availableRoom as r')
    ->selectRaw('*,r.roomDoorNum, r.isAvailable, rt.title as roomType,res.roomReservedID')
    ->join('roomtype as rt','rt.roomTypeID','=','r.roomTypeID')
    ->leftjoin('roomReserved as rr','rr.roomID','=','r.roomID')
    ->leftjoin('reservation as res','res.roomReservedID','=', DB::raw('rr.roomReservedID AND (res.reservationDate BETWEEN '."$checkInDate".' AND ' ."$checkOutDate". ' OR res.expiryDate BETWEEN '."$checkInDate".' AND ' ."$checkOutDate".')' ))
    ->get();

return $availableRooms;
```

Comment: Which version of SQL do you require? Please tag the question appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

No one really could do that for you. Tomorrow, you might need some other query to get into and explore. so My advice would be to install 
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar this package and it will take care of transforming eloquent query to raw query.